# Natural examples of elements of $C(X, X)$

Tags: continuity, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. The constant functions and the identity are easy examples of elements of $C(X, X)$. I know this question is quite inconcrete, but are there natural ways to construct other elements of $C(K, K)$?

Comment: Strange question... take $X=[0,1]$. There are many elements... exemple : $x\longmapsto x^{\alpha }$ for all $\alpha \geq 1$, or $x\longmapsto \sin(x)$ or $\underbrace{\text{many .... many}}_{n\ times}$ other functions

Comment: Of course in this concrete case there are many examples. I am wondering if there is a "method" to write down examples (aside from the constant functions and the identity) which works for arbitrary compact Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: @worldreporter14 I'd even say only identity is natural. For constants, you need to pick elements.

Comment: In spite of the fuzziness of  the question I think it's safe to say that given no more information about $X$ the answer is no.